# controller logic for included view files in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

As I am including elements/header.ctp file in another main.ctp file..

```
<?php echo $this->element('header'); ?>
```

I have included header in main.ctp it is displaying quite good. but when I am writing the query in ElementsController in is throwing an error undefined varible..
Below code for Elements Controller header() is the included file function.

```
    public function header()
{
    $this->set('marquee',$this->Newsmaster->find('all',array('order'=>array('Newsmaster.priority DESC'),'limit' =>20)));
   $userid = $this->Session->read('user');
}
```

can anyone help me in solving this please... thank You

Comment: What is your exact error? `undefined varible`

Comment: My first question will be for what do you need the $userid in your method, if you don't use it, or pass it to the View. An maybe will be a good Idea to look in Session for user_id, and not the entire user, or it's wrongly named ? Could you show us you header.ctp content, in order to make the 'relation' with your error.

Answer (score 0):

Elements Controller is not needed to set "marquee" varaible , you need to code in your usual controller for eg. for pages/index you will need to set variable in PagesController's index function  not in under ElementsController